# Nx/Nrwl - Angular Ui Library: How to construct the library-tree?

Tags: angular, monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl

Im starting a ui library inside my nx monorepo but Im unsure how to best organize it.
I have thought about these options:

- (1) a UI Library for each UI Component, where each Component has its own container module.
- (2) a UI Library for each UI Type, where there is one Module containing multiple component categories
- (3) a UI Library for each UI Type, where there is one Module for each component category
- (4) one UI Library for all Ui Components, where it contains a module for each ui component
- (5) one UI Library for all Ui Components, where we again have categorized the ui component types, bundling into modules

Here are showcases what I mean:

1. a UI Library for each UI Component, where each Component has its own container module.
   [image]
2. a UI Library for each UI Type, where there is one Module containing multiple component categories:
   [image]
3. a UI Library for each UI Type, where there is one Module for each component category:
   [image]
4. one UI Library for all Ui Components, where it contains a module for each ui component:[image]
5. one UI Library for all Ui Components, where we again have categorized the ui component types, bundling into modules:

   [image]

- Which option should I go for?
- What structure do you prefer?
- What is better and why?
- Are there other solutions?

Thank you in advance